# Find number of weekend days between two dates in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is an example of my spark df:

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|          OT|          Fecha_Fst|          Fecha_Lst|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|712268242652|2021-01-30 14:43:00|2021-02-03 13:03:00|
|712268243525|2021-01-30 14:27:00|2021-02-03 14:50:00|
|712268243831|2021-02-02 21:23:00|2021-02-08 17:39:00|
|712268244225|2021-02-01 07:26:00|2021-02-09 11:22:00|
|712268244951|2021-02-01 07:25:00|2021-02-05 16:07:00|
|712268245076|2021-02-01 07:26:00|2021-02-06 13:22:00|
|712268245651|2021-01-28 16:49:00|2021-02-04 13:31:00|
|712268246782|2021-02-01 07:26:00|2021-02-05 12:24:00|
|712268247644|2021-02-02 18:20:00|2021-02-05 16:12:00|
|712268247681|2021-02-09 05:03:00|2021-02-15 14:16:00|
|712268247751|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 13:27:00|
|712268247854|2021-01-30 14:34:00|2021-01-30 14:34:00|
|712268248775|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 12:42:00|
|712268249173|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 15:51:00|
|712268249873|2021-02-02 09:05:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|
|712268249884|2021-02-02 08:53:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|
|712268249895|2021-02-02 08:14:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|
|712268249906|2021-02-02 09:06:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|
|712268249910|2021-02-02 08:53:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|
|712268250186|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 18:59:00|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I found this code in the internet:

```
a = "2021-02-10T23:59:00.000+0000"
b = "2021-03-20T23:59:00.000+0000"
week = {}

def weekday_count(start, end):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")

    for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
        day = calendar.day_name[(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).weekday()]
        week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1
    return week["Sunday"] + week["Saturday"]

print(weekday_count(a, b))

11
```

It works fine and I get what I want but I can´t use it in my spark df I tried many forms but always get errors like:

```
df = df.withColumn("Number", weekday_count(f.col("Fecha_Fst"),f.col("Fecha_Lst")))
```

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Column

If I use lambda:

```
def weekday_count(start, end):
    start_date = lambda start :datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    end_date = lambda end :datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")

    for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
        day = calendar.day_name[(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).weekday()]
        week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1
    return week["Sunday"] + week["Saturday"]

df = df.withColumn("Number", weekday_count(f.col("Fecha_Fst"),f.col("Fecha_Lst")))
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and
> 'function'

And so on... I tried many forms today and don't get the desired result:

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
|          OT|          Fecha_Fst|          Fecha_Lst|       Days|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
|712268242652|2021-01-30 14:43:00|2021-02-03 13:03:00|          2|
|712268243831|2021-02-02 21:23:00|2021-02-08 17:39:00|          2|
|712268244225|2021-02-01 07:26:00|2021-02-09 11:22:00|          2| 
|712268244951|2021-02-01 07:25:00|2021-02-05 16:07:00|          0|
|712268247681|2021-02-09 05:03:00|2021-02-15 14:16:00|          2|
|712268247854|2021-01-30 14:34:00|2021-01-30 14:34:00|          1|
|712268248775|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 12:42:00|          0|
|712268249173|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 15:51:00|          0|
|712268249873|2021-02-02 09:05:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|          0|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I'm confused about how to work with new columns in the pyspark library, I used pandas but I'm currently working on azure databricks environment and pandas is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a python function directly. You need to create a [pyspark UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html).

However, you can actually get the desired result using spark built-in functions. Create a sequence of timestamps starting from `Fecha_Fst` to `Fecha_Lst` and then filter those which correspond to `Sat` or `Sun` days. The size of the resulting array is the number of weekends days.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

 df1 = df.withColumn(
    "Days",
    F.expr(
        """
        size(
            filter(
                sequence(Fecha_Fst, Fecha_Lst, interval 1 day),
                x -> date_format(x, 'E') in ('Sat', 'Sun')
            )
        )
        """
    )
) 

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
#|OT          |Fecha_Fst          |Fecha_Lst          |Days|
#+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
#|712268242652|2021-01-30 14:43:00|2021-02-03 13:03:00|2   |
#|712268243831|2021-02-02 21:23:00|2021-02-08 17:39:00|2   |
#|712268244225|2021-02-01 07:26:00|2021-02-09 11:22:00|2   |
#|712268244951|2021-02-01 07:25:00|2021-02-05 16:07:00|0   |
#|712268247681|2021-02-09 05:03:00|2021-02-15 14:16:00|2   |
#|712268247854|2021-01-30 14:34:00|2021-01-30 14:34:00|1   |
#|712268248775|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 12:42:00|0   |
#|712268249173|2021-02-02 15:42:00|2021-02-05 15:51:00|0   |
#|712268249873|2021-02-02 09:05:00|2021-02-05 19:36:00|0   |
#+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
```